# jQuery: How to use one function for different settings?

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```js
$('#font_one .font_size, #font_two .font_size').on('input', function() {
  var fontsizeval = $(this).val();
  var fontsizemin = $(this).attr('min');
  var fontsizemax = $(this).attr('max');
  $('#font_one .text, #font_two .text').css("font-size", fontsizeval + "px");
});
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.text {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="font_one">
  Font Size:
  <input class="font_size" type="range" value="20" min="10" max="50">
  <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>

<div id="font_two">
  Font Size:
  <input class="font_size" type="range" value="20" min="10" max="50">
  <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
```

I have to add a lot of fonts in the end. All fonts should be separately adjustable. It would be nice to have only one global function, and not to write the same code lines for every font. Is there a way to do that? Maybe with variables? The range sliders and the text area won't be in one div in the end, so it should not be done with `.siblings()`.

Would be very thankful for help! :)

Comment: If you apply a single class to many elements and then use a class selector instead of ID selectors, you can gather a whole set of matching elements and have them behave as you wish.

Comment: @Marc Thanks for your answer! The font sizes should be separately adjustable. Is it really better than to work with class selectors? And how does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an attribute to relate the slider with the corresponding DIV that it should control.

```js
$('.font_size').on('input', function() {
  var fontsizeval = $(this).val();
  var fontsizemin = $(this).attr('min');
  var fontsizemax = $(this).attr('max');
  var div = $("#" + $(this).data("rel"));
  div.css("font-size", fontsizeval + "px");
});
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.text {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="font_one">
  Font Size:
  <input class="font_size" type="range" value="20" min="10" max="50" data-rel="text1">
</div>

<div id="font_two">
  Font Size:
  <input class="font_size" type="range" value="20" min="10" max="50" data-rel="text2">
</div>

<div class="text" id="text1">Text</div>
<div class="text" id="text2">Text</div>
```

Comment: – Ohh no, I just realized that I can't work with ".siblings()". My text and my setting area will be split in the end, and not in one div. It guess it should be done with ID selectors. Sorry! Should I share more of my code?

Comment: You could use IDs and `data-rel="id"` attributes to relate the slider with the DIV that it controls.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much! <3<3<3